# Nested Switches and Default Subroutes with React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I keep getting the warning `Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on` when trying to navigate to `/articles/<article_id>/details`.

I currently have the following routes:

- `/`
- `/settings`
- `/settings/connections`
- `/articles`
- `/articles/:article_id`
- `/articles/:article_id/:author_id`
- `/articles/:article_id/:author_id/details`
- `/login`
- `/logout`

Here is what my main `Switch` looks like:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/articles" component={Articles} />
    <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
    <Redirect from="/" to="/articles" exact />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Then in `Articles.js` I have another `Switch`.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/articles/:article_id/details" component={ArticleDetail} />
  <Route path="/articles/:article_id/authors" component={ArticleAuthors} />
  <Route path="/articles/:article_id/authors/:author_id" component={ArticleAuthor} />
  <Route path="/articles/:article_id/authors/:author_id/details" component={ArticleAuthorDetails} />
  <Redirect from="/articles/:article_id" to="/articles/:article_id/details" exact />
</Switch>
```

Here's the issue:
When I navigate to `/articles/<article_id>/details` manually, I get the aforementioned warning. I've tried to manually check if the current route is on `/articles/<article_id>` or `/articles/<article_id>/` before redirecting, but this seems hacky/wrong.

Is there an easier way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Or am I misusing react router?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this working? 
If you could provide more code (or a repo) I could have a look.

I tried the following which worked for me (`react-router-dom` version 4.3.1)

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const Settings = () => (<div>Settings</div>);
const ArticleAuthors = () => (<div>ArticleAuthors</div>);
const ArticleDetail = () => (<div>ArticleDetail</div>);

const Articles = () => (
    <div>
        Articles
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/articles/:article_id/details" component={ArticleDetail} />
            <Route path="/articles/:article_id/authors" component={ArticleAuthors} />
            <Redirect from="/articles/:article_id" to="/articles/:article_id/details" exact />
        </Switch>
    </div>
);


const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/articles" component={Articles} />
            <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
            <Redirect from="/" to="/articles" exact />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);

export default App;
```